# move Sprite with touches moved

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, touchesmoved

i am moving a sprite using the touches moved method. currently the sprite jumps to the point on which the screen is touched but I want the sprite only to move when it is touched directly.

my code:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(location.x, self.size.height/2);

        self.sprite.position = newPosition;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You should check if the sprite is touched or not.
Check Ray's tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites). Then you should *break* the *for* loop when a touch is inside of a sprite bounds.

Comment: Why do you have a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if the touch location is inside the sprite, like this:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.sprite.boundingBox,positionInScene)) {

        CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(positionInScene.x, self.size.height/2);

        self.sprite.position = newPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i get the boundingBox?

Comment: if you are using Cocos2d CCSprite class, use `self.sprite.boundingBox`, if you are using SKNode class or UIView class, use `self.sprite.frame`